# Value is multiplied when condition is fulfiled

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

```
SELECT
C.ClientCaseNumber,
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (28, 29, 30) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Wezwania],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (14, 21) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Kontakt],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 32 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [SMS],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 44 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Zgon],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 49 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Areszt],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 37 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Odmowa],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 39 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Podważa],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 99 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Ugoda]
FROM   (SELECT cast(Notes as char) AS [Adres], CaseActionDefinitionId AS [Info1], NULL AS [Numer], NULL as      [Info2], NULL AS [Mail], NULL as [Info3], NULL AS [Powód], CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 68
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, cast(Info as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, NULL, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId IN (54, 55, 56, 58,
                                      59, 60, 61, 62, 63)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Notes as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 66
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Description as char(100)), CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionDefinition JOIN CaseActionHistory AS C ON DefinitionId = C.CaseActionDefinitionId
        WHERE  DefinitionId BETWEEN 70 AND 78) AS x
       INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
               ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
       INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
               ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
WHERE  C.ClientId = 11
GROUP  BY C.ClientCaseNumber
```

I've got a problem with sum(case). Whenever one of CaseActionHistory record is deleted (CA.IsDeleted ='True') values are multiplied x2 or sometimes even more without any reason. Running just a certain part of query ex:

```
SELECT
C.ClientCaseNumber
,Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (28, 29, 30) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Wezwania]
from
CaseActionHistory as CA
join CaseDetails as C on CA.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
where C.ClientId = '11'
group by CD.ClientCaseNumber
```

Sums records perfectly without any problems.

What is more I need to add an argument

```
....AS x
           INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
                   ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
           INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
                   ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
    WHERE  C.ClientId = 11 and CA.IsDeleted <> 'True'
    GROUP  BY C.ClientCaseNumber
```

However this screws all the counting and all sums are equal 0. But what is interesting using:

```
AS x
           INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
                   ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
           INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
                   ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
    WHERE  C.ClientId = 11 and CA.IsDeleted = 'True'
    GROUP  BY C.ClientCaseNumber
```

Works perfectly and it sums deleted codes.

IsDeleted can have three values: NULL/True/False with NULL as default. True after seting code as deleted; False after restoring the code.

---

```
declare @table table (
ClientCaseNumber int
,SetId int
,Wezwania int
,Kontakt int
,SMS int
,Zgon int
,Areszt int
,Odmowa int
,Podważa int
,Ugoda int
,Adres nvarchar(255)
,Info1 nvarchar(255)
,Numer nvarchar(255)
,Info2 nvarchar(255)
,Mail nvarchar(255)
,Info3 nvarchar(255)
,Powód nvarchar(255))

insert into @table (
ClientCaseNumber
,Wezwania
,Kontakt
,SMS
,Zgon
,Areszt
,Odmowa
,Podważa
,Ugoda)
SELECT
C.ClientCaseNumber,
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (28, 29, 30) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Wezwania],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (14, 21) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Kontakt],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 32 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [SMS],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 44 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Zgon],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 49 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Areszt],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 37 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Odmowa],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 39 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Podważa],
Sum(CASE
        WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 99 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [Ugoda]
FROM   (SELECT cast(Notes as char) AS [Adres], CaseActionDefinitionId AS [Info1], NULL AS [Numer], NULL as      [Info2], NULL AS [Mail], NULL as [Info3], NULL AS [Powód], CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 68
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, cast(Info as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, NULL, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId IN (54, 55, 56, 58,
                                      59, 60, 61, 62, 63)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Notes as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 66
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Description as char(100)), CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionDefinition JOIN CaseActionHistory AS C ON DefinitionId = C.CaseActionDefinitionId
        WHERE  DefinitionId BETWEEN 70 AND 78) AS x
       INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
               ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
       INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
               ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
WHERE  C.ClientId = 11 and (CA.IsDeleted <> 'True' OR CA.IsDeleted IS NULL)
GROUP  BY C.ClientCaseNumber

update @table
set SetId = X.SetId
, Adres = X.Adres
,Info1 = X.Info1
,Numer = X.Numer
,Info2 = X.Info2
,Mail = X.Mail
,Info3 = X.Info3
,Powód = X.Powód
from
@table as T
join (
SELECT
    C.ClientCaseNumber,
    C.ClientId,
    C.SetId,
    [Adres],
    [Info1],
    [Numer],
    [Info2],
    [Mail],
    [Info3],
    [Powód]
FROM   (SELECT cast(Notes as char) AS [Adres], CaseActionDefinitionId AS [Info1], NULL AS [Numer], NULL as [Info2], NULL AS [Mail], NULL as [Info3], NULL AS [Powód], CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 68
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, cast(Info as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, NULL, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId IN (54, 55, 56, 58,
                                      59, 60, 61, 62, 63)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Notes as char), CaseActionDefinitionId, NULL, CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 66
    UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, cast(Description as char(100)), CaseDetailId
        FROM   CaseActionDefinition JOIN CaseActionHistory AS C ON DefinitionId = C.CaseActionDefinitionId
        WHERE  DefinitionId BETWEEN 70 AND 78) AS x
       INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
               ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
       INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
               ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
    WHERE
        C.ClientId = 11
) as X on X.ClientCaseNumber = T.ClientCaseNumber

SELECT DISTINCT ClientCaseNumber,
            SetId,
           [Wezwania],
           [Kontakt],
           [SMS],
           [Zgon],
           [Areszt],
           [Odmowa],
           [Podważa],
           [Ugoda],
           [Adres],
           [Info1],
           [Numer],
           [Info2],
           [Mail],
           [Info3],
           [Powód]
    FROM  @table
```

Comment: Try change to `ISNULL(CA.IsDeleted, 0) <> 0`

Comment: Nope. Shows completely different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
CA.IsDeleted <> 'True'
```

to

```
(CA.IsDeleted <> 'True' OR CA.IsDeleted IS NULL)
```

Comment: Works. However still doubles or triples values completely randomly without any reason

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which part of the code above I would have to check. There's quite a lot of it and I'm not sure which bit is failing.

Comment: Ok so I made so check outs. After removing sub select (marked as X) and puttin from CaseActionHistory as CA instead of this one it works fine.

Comment: Good to hear. So all problems sorted out?

Comment: Not really since I rly need this subquery ;). I found a source of problem but still lf solution

Comment: I guess your INNER JOIN causes duplication as it has 1 to many relationship with some child tables.

Comment: Probably. However I don't really see a way to not use this one relationship

Comment: Updated first post with whole query

Comment: Can't rewrite it now as I'm using my mobile but basically do sums in one select just on caseactionhistory. Then do a join to the child table from the sums.

Comment: I think I found a soultion. Just removed subquery from insert into @table. At least I think it works fine. Marking your post as solution. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(isnull(CA.IsDeleted,'')='' or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
```